# Hibernate (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, hql

I am working with NetBeans and when I write an HQL query I see some weird results, when I make a query, at the HQL Editor, like this `from User`, it returns what I expect, but If I write: `select a.name from User a`, it returns nothing, just types names at the column name `query(Char Char Byte Byte)`, although it says the number of records. Anyone has seen this before?

Comment: Can you print out the SQL (show_sql in Hibernate) and run that on the RDBMS? How many rows are returned?

Comment: You are Right. I copied the sql generated and run it out of it and the result was what I expected. But any way I don't know why it doesn't return it right at the NetBean HQL Editor. But thanks a lot because at least I have a result now, doing more steps.

Comment: could it be that the generated query somehow has a keyword for your RDBMS that isn't handled properly? Try selecting a different property, see what happens. (if that works maybe file a bug with the netbeans guys)

Answer (score 0):

When you use HQL as `select a.name from User a`, it should return `String[]` assuming `a.name` is String type. Please update the result retrieval/iteration accordingly and print the output. It should be working.

Comment: I Agree it should work, because I have done it at my Java code and everything is fine, but I want to see the results at the HQL editor for testing when I am working with difficult queries. Anyway thanks a lot..